# Is there a shortcut to jump to the Top/Bottom of the current page in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I know how to jump to the top or bottom of the document;
To jump to the top of the document: <kbd>HOME</kbd>
To jump to the bottom/end of the document: <kbd>END</kbd>

Is there a shortcut to jump to the Top/Bottom of the current page?

Comment: How about `Page Up` and `Page Down`?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+N should go top the top of the current page, where N is the current page number. Otherwise you can try Ctrl+Page Down/Ctrl+Page Up (Jump one page down/one page up)